# SageMaker Studio Lab, "Make AI Generated Images" lab, Error "Found no NVIDIA driver on your system"

Tags: nvidia, amazon-sagemaker-studio

During this lab while pipeline construction

(import torch
from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline

pipeline = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(
"runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5", torch_dtype=torch.float16, revision="fp16"
)

pipeline = pipeline.to("cuda")

I got the following runtime error :

RuntimeError: Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx

Any hint to solve this ?

Thanks in advance

I am a new comer and attempted without effect the commands found at
https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a GPU based instance for Studio Lab, what is the instance you are utilizing behind your Studio Lab environment?